# Checking a Boolean inside of an if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean

Today I've come across a problem in Javascript that I can't understand at all.

I have this code:

```js
var status = false;
console.log(status, typeof status);
if (status) {
  console.log("status is true");
} else {
  console.log("status is false");
}
```

I expected it would not satisfy the `if` statement, since `status` is `false`. Moreover, it's a Boolean, not a String.

I was wrong. It returned `"status is true"`, so `status` **did satisfy the `if` statement**.

I changed my code to specify a condition, not just the variable:

```js
var status = false;
console.log(status, typeof status);
if (status == false) {
  console.log("status is false");
} else {
  console.log("status is not false");
}
```

Notice that I switched the output messages, since we're not checking the value of the variable itself, but checking if it's `false` or not.

I really started to panic when I read `"status is not false"` on the console. How can it be other thing than `false`?

What am I missing?

Comment: Use a different variable name, or put it all inside an IIFE, or use `const` instead of `var` (because `window.status` will always be a string, like `window.name`)

Comment: I'm not sure why you're experiencing this. I tested your code and got the correct result.

Comment: @RyanWalls If you paste and run the code on the top level, you'll experience it too.

Comment: @CertainPerformance It looks like it was the name of the variable. I can't thank you enough.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are experiencing this because status is a reserved word in js. Use another variable name like stat and it will work just fine.

For more [info](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp)

```js
var stat = false;
if(stat){
    console.log("status is true");
} else {
    console.log("status is false");
}
```